# Why is this program for extracting IDs from a file so slow?

Tags: python, optimization, array

This is roughly what my data file looks like:

```
# Monid      U        B       V       R       I      u       g        r       i       J      Jerr     H      Herr      K      Kerr   IRAC1    I1err  IRAC2    I2err  IRAC3    I3err  IRAC4    I4err  MIPS24  M24err  SpT    HaEW       mem comp
Mon-000001  99.999  99.999  21.427  99.999  18.844  99.999  99.999  99.999  99.999  16.144  99.999  15.809   0.137  16.249  99.999  15.274   0.033  15.286   0.038  99.999  99.999  99.999  99.999  99.999  99.999  null   55.000        1  N
Mon-000002  99.999  99.999  20.905  19.410  17.517  99.999  99.999  99.999  99.999  15.601   0.080  15.312   0.100  14.810   0.110  14.467   0.013  14.328   0.019  14.276   0.103  99.999   0.048  99.999  99.999  null  -99.999        2  N
```

...and it's a total of 31mb in size. Here's my python script that pulls the Mon-###### IDs 
(found at the beginning of each of the lines).

```
import re

def pullIDs(file_input):
    '''Pulls Mon-IDs from input file.'''

    arrayID = []
    with open(file_input,'rU') as user_file:
        for line in user_file:
            arrayID.append(re.findall('Mon\-\d{6}',line))
    return arrayID

print pullIDs(raw_input("Enter your first file: "))
```

The script works but for this particular file it ran for well into 5 minutes and I eventually just killed the process due to impatience. Is this just something I'll have to deal with in python? i.e. Should this be written with a compiled language considering the size of my data file?

Further info:
  This script is being run within Emacs. This, by the checked answer, explains why it was running so slow.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. When I tried it, your program reads the ids from a 31 MiB file in less than a second. So I think there must be something you're not telling us.

Comment: The only thing that might be of interest is that I'm running it through Emacs on a macbook pro.

Comment: Me too, so that can't be it. Can you post a self-contained test case? For example, you could write some code that generates 31 MiB of test data, and then we could check our timing against yours on the same data.

Comment: Hmmmm. I'd like to do that, but I wouldn't even know where to start with it. That's a little bit advanced for my level. I'd like to learn though if you wouldn't mine explaining how to go about doing that...

Comment: @GarethRees A second thing I just discovered...if I run the script in my terminal it finishes in about 2 seconds. It also completes within Eclipse Kepler within about 3 to 4 seconds. Hmmmm, Emacs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said in comments that you don't know how to create a self-contained test case. But that's really easy! All that's needed is a function like this:

```
def test_case(filename, n):
    """Write n lines of test data to filename."""
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        for i in range(n):
            f.write('Mon-{0:06d} {1}\n'.format(i + 1, '  99.999' * 20))
```

You can use this to make a test case of about the right size:

```
>>> test_case('cr36275.data', 200000)
>>> import os
>>> os.stat('cr36275.data').st_size
34400000
```

That's about 34 MiB so close enough. Now we can see how fast your code really is, using the [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) module:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit(lambda:pullIDs('cr36275.data'), number=1)
1.3354740142822266
```

Just over a second. There's nothing wrong with your code or the speed of Python.

So why does it take you many minutes? Well, you say that you're running it inside Emacs. That means that when you run

```
>>> pullIDs('cr36275.data')
```

Python prints out a list of 200,000 ids, and Emacs reads this line of output into the `*Python*` buffer and *applies syntax highlighting rules to it as it goes*. Emacs' syntax highlighting code is designed to work on lines of source code (at most a few hundred characters but mostly 80 characters or less), not on lines of output that are millions of characters long. This is what is taking all the time.

So don't do that. Read the list of ids into a variable and if you need to look at it, use slicing to look at bits of it:

```
>>> ids = pullIDs('cr36275.data')
>>> ids[:10]
[['Mon-000001'], ['Mon-000002'], ['Mon-000003'], ['Mon-000004'], ['Mon-000005'],
 ['Mon-000006'], ['Mon-000007'], ['Mon-000008'], ['Mon-000009'], ['Mon-000010']]
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much for this. It isn't crucial that I print these IDs to my screen but I wanted to see if my script was working correctly and this crazy slow down kind of confused me. But, you've cleared all of that up. Thanks for the test-case pointers and the insight into Emacs.

Answer (score 3):

If you know that `Mon-######` IDS will always be in the first part of each line there is no need to `.findall(..)`, just extract the first 10 characters from the line (granted the `Mon-######` is never more than 10 characters

Comment: If it isn't though would this be the only way? I only ask because I plan on using this on multiple files, some of which may not have the IDs in the first part of the line. Thanks.

Comment: Another thing could be to change .findall(..) to only finding the first instance (if there are some kind of .find() or .findfirst()). The difference would be that instead of traversing the entire line it only traverses it until it's found, a small improvement but I guess it adds up.

Comment: @Max: Did you try any of these suggestions? How much improvement to the runtime did they make?

Comment: No I didn't try it, and I don't expect it to be any major improvements, but when you're after performance boosts I guess it all adds up.